# Serialise a class that contains a Bitmap

Tags: android, object, serialization, bitmap

I have a custom class as below

public class GeneralObject implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String caption;
private String imageName;
private String postid;
private Bitmap bitmap;

//setters
public void setImage(String imageName){
    this.imageName = imageName;
}

public void setCaption(String caption){
    this.caption = caption;
}

public void setPostId(String postid){
    this.postid = postid;
}

public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    this.bitmap = bitmap;
}

//getters
public String getCaption(){
    return caption;
}

public String getImage(){
    return imageName;
}

public Bitmap getBitmap() {
    return bitmap;
}

public String getPostId(){
    return postid;
}
```

}

and I am trying to serialise it using the following code

public final class SerializeTest {

```
private SerializeTest(){}

public static void writeObject(Context context, String key, Object object) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(object);
    oos.close();
    fos.close();
}

public static Object readObject(Context context, String key) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(key);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    Object object = ois.readObject();
    return object;
}
```

}

But I am getting the exception "java.io.notserializableexception android.graphics.bitmap". I know this happens because I have a bitmap inside the object. Can someone suggest me a solution for this? I mean a way to serialise the bitmap and the data of the object? An example code would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why not to make it Parcelable?

Comment: Will it solve the problem by just implementing the class using Parcelable? Do I need any additional code in the overridden methods ("describeContents" and "writeToParcel") ? I will give it go

Comment: see http://www.parcelabler.com/

Comment: thanks, but what parameter shall I pass into  " protected PlaceObject(Parcel in)" when declaring PlaceObject pl = new PlaceObject(?)

Comment: you need to pass a Parcel, read its docs

Comment: thanks but, I have already checked it, but I don't understand what is need to be passed according to my code above.

Comment: use Parcel.obtain(). again read the docs carefully